# How to split dataframe columns into row values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe with more descriptions for products.

```
data = {'product': ['1234', '5678'],
        'descriptionOLD': ['old1234', 'old5678'],
        'descriptionNEW': ['new1234', 'new5678'],
        'descriptionFUTURE': ['future1234', 'future5678'],
        }
```

How can i split this dataframe in this kind of format?

```
product type            description
1234    descriptionOLD  old1234
1234    descriptionOLD  old5678
1234    descriptionNEW  new1234
1234    descriptionNEW  new5678
1234    descriptionFUTURE future1234
1234    descriptionFUTURE future5678
...
```

So far i have tried:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df['type']=''
df['description']=''
for id, row in df.iterrows():
    df['type'][id]='descriptionOLD'
    df['description'][id]=row['descriptionOLD']

df.pop('descriptionOLD')
df.pop('descriptionNEW')
df.pop('descriptionFUTURE')
```

and it gets me this result:

```
  product            type description
0    1234  descriptionOLD     old1234
1    5678  descriptionOLD     old5678
```

but i don't know how to handle the new and future descriptions as well to achieve the desired dataframe.

Comment: @AnuragDabas and what if there are more columns and I only want to melt the df for the description part?

Comment: did you get your expected output?

Answer (score 3):

try via `filter()` method for filtering out columns,`join()` method for getting back the 'product' column and finally `melt()` method:

```
out=(df.filter(like='description')
   .join(df['product'])
    .melt(id_vars='product',var_name='type',value_name='description'))
```

**OR**

try via `filter()` method for filtering out columns,`set_index()` method for preserving the 'products',`reset_index()` for making product back to column and finally `melt()` method:

```
out=(df.set_index('product')
       .filter(like='description')
       .reset_index()
       .melt(id_vars='product',var_name='type',value_name='description'))
```

**OR**

As suggested by `@NK03` you can also use a combo of `filter()` and `stack()`:

```
out=(df.set_index('product')
       .filter(like='description')
        .stack()
        .reset_index(name ='description')
        .rename(columns = {'level_1' : 'type'}))
```

Comment: I guess there's no need for melt -> `df.set_index('product').stack().reset_index(name ='description').rename(columns = {'level_1' : 'type'})`

Comment: yes brother....It will also work but we have to chain  5 methods for its working

Comment: @Nk03 bhai pls undelete your answer on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67915609/plotting-sets-from-pandas-df-and-type-error-unhashable-type-set/67915633#67915633 since plot without using seaborn was your answer

Comment: Bro, it's okay!!.  I also like seaborn more.. :p