# Plotting sets from Pandas df and Type Error unhashable type: 'set'

Tags: python, pandas, plot, seaborn, typeerror

I have a dataframe with a column of sets:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Alex',{33, 34}],['Bob',{33}],['Clarke',{33, 34}]], columns = ['names', 'indicators']).
```

I would like to plot the frequency of values in df['indicators'] to get a sense of what combinations of indicators take place. I.e., here I'd like a plot that shows {33, 34} shows up twice and {33} shows up once. Letting seaborn be sb, I'd normally make a histogram:

```
sb.countplot(data = df, x = 'indicators')
```

But I get TypeError: unhashable type: 'set' when I try this. I've tried converting the arguments from sets to lists or np.array() to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import seaborn as sns
```

try via `astype()`:

```
sns.countplot(data = df.astype({'indicators':'str'}), x = 'indicators')
#the 'indicators' column in you real dataset won't change
```

**OR**

```
df['indicators']=df['indicators'].astype(str)
#Finally:
sns.countplot(data = df, x = 'indicators')
#For making back the the 'indicators' column back to set you can use:
df['indicators']=df['indicators'].str.strip('{}').str.split(',').map(set)
```

output:

[image]

Comment: This is not quite what I want. I'm trying to see which indicators show up with one another, so I want a plot which shows {33, 34} has frequency of 2 and {33} has frequency of 1. You've shows that {33} has a frequency of 3 and {34} has a frequency of 2.

Comment: @shaha updated answer...Kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: Thanks. :) This is what I've figured out for now too. I'd prefer not to turn everything into strings as it's less mutable that way, though it works! I've upvoted your comment for now, if nobody else can give a direct answer in the next few hours I'll accept it.

Comment: Updated answer for that as well...Kindly have a look **:)**